# How to get data from SQLite databse in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to get some data from my database I have created using my application. Here is my code

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.select_to_delete);

database = new DatabaseHandler(this);

bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
date = bundle.getString("DATE");

SQLiteDatabase db=database.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT " +TITLE+  " FROM " +TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + CDATE + "=" + date,null);


int i = cur.getCount();


if(cur !=null){
    if (cur.moveToFirst()){
           do{
              tdate = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("DATE"));
              titlearray.add(tdate);
           }while(cur.moveToNext());
        }

}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titlearray);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My table has 5 columns (id, title, date, time, descrption). and have 4 raws. **The table is created in another class**.

When I run this application it doesn't get the data from the sql table and show it in listview. When I debug it, it shows `i=1` and the it returns false to `if (cur.moveToFirst())`. So it doesn't go inside that `if` part.

What could my mistake be?

Comment: If you want existing database, follow this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place apostrophe (') around your date

```
Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT " +TITLE+  " FROM " +TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + CDATE + "='" + date+"'",null);
```

N.B. I am assuming your table creation and other field names are accurate. Also recheck those

Answer (score 1):

Use selection args and you will be avoiding tons of problems:

```
Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT " +TITLE+  " FROM " +TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + CDATE + " = ?", new String[] { date });
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { TITLE}, CDATE + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(date) }, null, null, null, null);
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
           //add to the array
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```